# HP Pavillion Aero laptop slow keyboard response and touchpad freezes on Ubuntu 23.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, touchpad, 23.04

Recently, I bought an HP Pavillion Aero 13 laptop. The Windows 11 was pre-installed, but I installed Ubuntu 23.04 in dual boot. The problem is that the built-in keyboard awfully lags: it takes like 0.5 seconds for every key pressed to be reflected on the screen (whatever application I am typing in). Another issue (which might be related) is that the touchpad sometimes freezes and the mouse cursor stops moving at all (while the keyboard still works, though still slowly).

To test, I tried to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS instead - and I experienced exactly the same problems.

From the solutions online, I checked if the "slow keys" were turned off, I tried the previous kernel (available from the Ubuntu boot menu) - but nothing helped.

P.S. If I boot to Windows, both the keyboard and the touchpad work perfectly fine.

**UPD:** The issue was completely resolved out of the box in Ubuntu 23.10, and it works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was completely resolved out of the box in Ubuntu 23.10, and it works perfectly fine now. (Perhaps because of the new Linux kernel?..)

Comment: Well, the problem was slow keyboard response. Upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10 solved the problem. Obviously, it doesn't answer the question of WHY the upgrade resolves the issue but it does. I guess it might be still helpful to those encountering the problem. Your help with better phrasing/formatting/formulating is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I would retract my vote if I could. I experienced similar problems with different versions of Ubuntu with other problems. Your answer is surely helpful.